# Flex DataGrid: Change value based on another value?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in Flex, with one column a checkbox and another a numeric value. When the checkbox is clicked, the numeric value should change, either to 0 if the checkbox is unselected, or to a pre-defined minimum value if the checkbox is selected. Here is the code I have:

```
<mx:DataGrid x="0" y="45" width="272" height="525" dataProvider="{dp}" variableRowHeight="true" editable="true" id="equipmentDG" verticalAlign="middle">                
    <mx:columns>                    

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="" headerStyleName="gridheader" width="20" dataField="included" editorDataField="selected" rendererIsEditor="true">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:CheckBox click="handleClicks(event)">
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[
                            public function handleClicks(event:MouseEvent):void
                            {
                                data.included = !data.included;

                                if(data.included && data.antal == 0)     
                                    data.antal = data.minNo; 
                                else if(!data.included) 
                                    data.antal = 0;
                            }
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>
                    </mx:CheckBox>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Antal" headerStyleName="gridheader" width="40" dataField="antal" editorDataField="value" editable="true">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>

                    <mx:NumericStepper stepSize="1" width="35" height="20"  focusOut="numericstepper1_changeHandler(event)">
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[
                            import mx.events.NumericStepperEvent;
                            override public function set data(value:Object):void
                            {
                                super.data = value;

                                if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("minNo"))
                                    minimum = value.minNo;

                                if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("maxNo"))
                                    maximum = value.maxNo;                                              
                            }

                            protected function numericstepper1_changeHandler(event:Event):void
                            {
                                if(data.antal > 0)
                                    data.included = true;
                                else
                                    data.included = false;
                            }

                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>

                    </mx:NumericStepper>                                        

                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>


    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

The value updates in the data (I can see it when I close and open the dialog this is in), but it doesn't update instantly in the data grid. How can I make the value visibly change as soon as the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data object, make sure to fire an event every time the included property changes.  In your 2nd itemRenderer listen to the event and update the value whenever the property changes.

Conceptually like this:

In the data object:

```
private var _included : Boolean;
public function get included():Boolean{
 return this._included;
}

public function set included(value:Boolean):void
 this._included = value;
 this.dispatchEvent(new Event('includedChanged');
}
```

Add a renderer to your second column, like this:

```
 <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Antal" headerStyleName="gridheader" width="40" dataField="antal" editorDataField="value" editable="true">
  <mx:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
   <mx:Label dataChange="onDataChange()" >
    <fx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
      public function onDataChange():void{
       thistext = data['Antal'];
       this.data.addEventListener('includedChanged',onIncludedChange);
      }
      public function onIncludedChange(e:Event):void{
       this.text = data['Antal'];
      }
     ]]>
    </fx:Script>
   </mx:Label>
  </fx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
  <mx:itemEditor>
   <fx:Component>

    <mx:NumericStepper stepSize="1" width="35" height="20"  focusOut="numericstepper1_changeHandler(event)">
     <fx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
       import mx.events.NumericStepperEvent;
       override public function set data(value:Object):void{
        super.data = value;

        if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("minNo"))
         minimum = value.minNo;

        if (value && value.hasOwnProperty("maxNo"))
          maximum = value.maxNo;                                              
        }

        protected function numericstepper1_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
         if(data.antal > 0)
          data.included = true;
         else
          data.included = false;
         }

         ]]>
        </fx:Script>
       </mx:NumericStepper>                                        
      </fx:Component>
     </mx:itemEditor>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the minimum and maximum I need to set this time, it's the actual value (data.antal). It's being set in the dataprovider but doesn't show up in the datagrid until I reset the dataprovider for the datagrid.

Comment: The code is still the basic concept of how it should work.  Since you're not actually displaying the 'antal' value anywhere in your code; I'm not sure what visual piece you're trying to update

Comment: The 'antal' value is what is shown in the second column in the datagrid. That is what isn't visibly updated the moment I click the checkbox.

Comment: Code updated.  Conceptually, just add a renderer to your second column and update the label's text when the change event fires.

Answer (score 1):

I would just mark antal as [Bindable] and use dp as an ArrayCollection.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the *quick-and-dirty* approach: re-assign the `dataProvider`. That should force an invalidation of the DataGrid.

Comment: Although this will work; it is a very performance heavy solution.

Comment: @Flextras, yes that's quick-and-dirty. :-)

Comment: Thanks, yes it works, and my dataprovider only holds less than 20 items so it feels really snappy too. But preferably, less dirty is better...at least when it comes to code...;-)