# Get ItemRenderer for a particular cell - Flex DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, datagrid, runtime, itemrenderer

I have a datagrid with 2 columns. I need to access the item renderer of the second column whenever column-1 value changes. i.e if value of column 1 is A- need to display text field in column2 and if value is B, i need to show dropdown.

Col1----------Col2

A ---------- DropDown

B ---------- TextBox

A ---------- DropDown

Any Solutions???

```
public class ItemRendererfroDropTest extends GridItemRenderer
{
    private var dropdown:DropDownList;
    public function ItemRendererfroDropTest()
    {
        super();
        dropdown=new DropDownList();
        dropdown.dataProvider=new ArrayCollection(new Array("ABC","PQR"));
        this.addElement(dropdown);
        dropdown.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT,dataChanged);
    }

    private function dataChanged(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        owner.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.DATA_CHANGED,true));
    }

}


public class ItemRenderlabel extends GridItemRenderer
{
    public var wlabel:Label=new Label();
    public var checkbox:CheckBox=new CheckBox();

    public function ItemRenderlabel()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.DATA_CHANGED,mappingChanged,true);
        this.addElement(wlabel);
    }
    private function mappingChanged(e:CustomEvent):void
    {
        Alert.show("asfAS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the DataGrid.createItemRenderer() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some idea from below code: - Event you can do it only for particular item by using dpHierarchy.itemUpdated() by updating individual row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection([
                {name:"A", region: "Arizona"},
                {name:"B", region: "Arizona"},
                {name:"C", region: "California"},
                {name:"D", region: "California"}
            ]); 

            private function init():void
            {
                this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE, changeDataHandler);
            }

            private function changeDataHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                dpHierarchy.refresh();
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" 
                         width="100%" height="100%" 
                         variableRowHeight="true" dataProvider="{dpHierarchy}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" itemRenderer="AddComboboxADG"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="region" headerText="Region" itemRenderer="SelectedCustomComponent"/>
        </mx:columns>   

    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

//AddComboboxADG custom item renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer;
            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridListData;
            import mx.events.AdvancedDataGridEvent;
            import mx.events.DataGridEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;

            import spark.components.supportClasses.ItemRenderer;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;


            protected function comboBoxID_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                data.name = comboBoxID.selectedItem;
                dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE, true));
            }

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;

                if(data.name == "A")
                {
                    comboBoxID.selectedIndex = 0;
                }else if(data.name == "B")
                {
                    comboBoxID.selectedIndex = 1;
                }else if(data.name == "C")
                {
                    comboBoxID.selectedIndex = 2;   
                }else
                {
                    comboBoxID.selectedIndex = 3;
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DropDownList id="comboBoxID" change="comboBoxID_changeHandler(event)">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>A</fx:String>
            <fx:String>B</fx:String>
            <fx:String>C</fx:String>
            <fx:String>D</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:DropDownList>
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```

//SelectedCustomComponent custom item renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                customFirstDropDown.visible = customTextInput.visible = customSecondDropDown.visible = lblData.visible = false;

                if(data.name == "A")
                {
                    customFirstDropDown.visible = true;
                }else if(data.name == "B")
                {
                    customTextInput.visible = true;
                }else if(data.name == "C")
                {
                    customSecondDropDown.visible = true;    
                }else
                {
                    lblData.visible = true;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DropDownList id="customFirstDropDown" visible="false" selectedIndex="0">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>First</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Second</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Third</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:DropDownList>
    <s:TextInput id="customTextInput" visible="false" text="Selected"/>
    <s:DropDownList id="customSecondDropDown" visible="false" selectedIndex="0">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>1</fx:String>
            <fx:String>2</fx:String>
            <fx:String>3</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:DropDownList>   

    <s:Label id="lblData" visible="false" text="Selected"/>
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. This is exactly what i was looking for.
Should this work with the spark DataGrid aswell??

Answer (score 0):

Create Item renderer using [ViewStack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e4d.html) with views as required, and override data function as normally done for item renderer, to set active child of container base of field, If you wants to set Active child on fly see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854973/flex-datagrid-change-value-based-on-another-value)

Hopes that helps

Comment: Thanks Imran, 
Let me try firing the event, as shown in the example.

Comment: I dispatched a custom event, but it is not captured in the other item-renderer(one which is listening). :(

Comment: Code added. Both renderers falls into a grid.